# Lambda Calculus CONS Pair implementation with Lisp

Tags: lisp, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to implement a Church Pair Lambda Calc. style with CLisp.

According with Wikipedia:

> ```
> pair ≡ λx.λy.λz.z x y
> ```

So far, this is my code:

```
 (defvar PAIR
         #'(lambda(x)
                 #'(lambda(y)
                         #'(lambda(z)
                                 (funcall (funcall z x) y)))) )
```

These are my FIRST and SECOND Functions:

```
(defvar FIRST
        #'(lambda(p)
                (funcall(p TRUE)))
)

(defvar SECOND
        #'(lambda(p)
                (funcall(p FALSE)))
)
```

This 2 functions convert from Int to ChurchNumber

```
(defun church2int(numchurch)
    (funcall (funcall numchurch #'(lambda (x) (+ x 1))) 0)
)

(defun int2church(n)
    (cond
        ((= n 0) #'(lambda(f) #'(lambda(x)x)))
        (t #'(lambda(f) #'(lambda(x) (funcall f
            (funcall(funcall(int2church (- n 1))f)x))))))

)
```

So, what I do is:

```
(setq six (int2church 6))
(setq four (int2church 4))
```

And then:

```
(setq P (funcall (funcall PAIR six) four))
```

And the I've got:

```
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (Y) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL F X) Y)>
```

So if I do this:

```
(funcall #'FIRST P)
```

I've got the this error:

```
*** - FIRST: #<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (Y) (FUNCALL (FUNCALL F X) Y)> is not a list
```

I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're using `#'FIRST`.
   That means it's using the *function* FIRST, not the variable you defined. `FIRST` (from the standard library) is another name for `car`, i.e. it returns the first element of a list (hence the error complaining about `P` not being a list).
   Fix: `(funcall FIRST P)`
   That will cause the error `*** - EVAL: undefined function P`
2. This is caused by your definition of `FIRST`: `#'(lambda (p) (funcall (p TRUE)))`
   What this means is: Return a lambda function with a single parameter `p`. That parameter is ignored. Instead, call the global function `p` passing the value of the variable `TRUE` as an argument: `(p TRUE)`. Then call the result of `p` as (another) function: `(funcall ...)`.
   Fix: `#'(lambda (p) (funcall p TRUE))`
   That will cause the error `*** - :LAMBDA: variable TRUE has no value`
3. That's because you haven't actually defined `TRUE` and `FALSE` yet.
   Fix: Define `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to include TRUE and FALSE definitions in the post, but they are implemented in my code

Comment: Exceptional answer! (..... and that's why, ladies and gentlemen, Scheme is a Lisp-1.)