# Use of lambda for cons/car/cdr definition in SICP

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, sicp

I was just beginning to feel I had a vague understanding of the use of lambda in racket and scheme when I came across the following 'alternate' definitions for cons and car in SICP

```
(define (cons x y)
   (lambda (m) (m x y)))

(define (car z)
  (z (lambda (p q) p)))

(define (cdr z)
  (z (lambda (p q) q)))
```

For the life of me I just cannot parse them.

Can anybody explain how to parse or expand these in a way that makes sense for total neophytes?

Comment: You might be interested in [How is set! defined in scheme?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16733472/1281433) where the accepted answer shows how to implement a cell that stores one value.  It's the same sort of idea.  Also see [Lambda Calculus CONS Pair implementation with Lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13537622/1281433) which has a definition like yours: `pair ≡ λx.λy.λz.z x y`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an interesting way to represent data: as functions. Notice that this
definition of `cons` returns a `lambda` which *closes over* the parameters `x`
and `y`, capturing their values inside. Also notice that the returned lambda
receives a *function* `m` as a parameter:

```
;creates a closure that "remembers' 2 values
(define (cons x y)    (lambda (m) (m x y)))
;recieves a cons holding 2 values, returning the 0th value
(define (car z)       (z (lambda (p q) p)))
;recieves a cons holding 2 values, returning the 1st value
(define (cdr z)       (z (lambda (p q) q)))
```

In the above code `z` is a closure, the same that was created by `cons`, and in
the body of the procedure we're passing it *another* `lambda` as parameter,
remember `m`? it's just that! the function that it was expecting.

Understanding the above, it's easy to see how `car` and `cdr` work; let's
dissect how `car`, `cdr` is evaluated by the interpreter one step at a time:

```
; lets say we started with a closure `cons`, passed in to `car`
(car (cons 1 2))

; the definition of `cons` is substituted in to `(cons 1 2)` resulting in:
(car (lambda (m) (m 1 2)))

; substitute `car` with its definition
((lambda (m) (m 1 2)) (lambda (p q) p))

; replace `m` with the passed parameter
((lambda (p q) p) 1 2)

; bind 1 to `p` and 2 to `q`, return p
1
```

To summarize: `cons` creates a closure that "remembers' two values, `car`
receives that closure and passes it along a function that acts as a selector for
the zeroth value, and `cdr` acts as a selector for the 1st value. The key
point to understand here is that `lambda` acts as a
[closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).
How cool is this? we only need functions to store and retrieve arbitrary data!

Nested Compositions of `car` & `cdr` are [defined up to 4 deep](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_402) in most LISPs. example:

```
(define caddr (lambda (x) (car (cdr (cdr x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I get it (but it makes my brain hurt). This is much more complicated that the other alternate version they describe of the form: (define (cons x y)
  (define (dispatch m)
    (cond ((= m 0) x)
          ((= m 1) y)))
  dispatch)

(define (car z) (z 0))    Looks like I need to understand closures - thanks for the reference to them.

Comment: The other alternative is more complicated, conceptually. It requires conditionals, comparisons, functions and function application - whereas this alternative only requires functions and function application.

Comment: Maybe because I am not familiar with functional languages yet, the second seems simpler to me. To my mind, in the 'dispatch' alternative, cons produces a function that is lurking in wait to produce the correct output when asked nicely - this seems simple. But in the 'lambda' alternative cons, produces a phantom that can only be made sense of when it is "boot-strapped" by car.

Comment: In both cases there's a function lurking, waiting to be asked nicely :)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez SO made me wait 24 hours to award the 250pt bounty, also I submitted an edit adding info about nested `cdadr`s, hope you approve ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my view, the definitive trick is reading the definitions **from the end to the beginning**, because in all three of them the free variables are always those that can be found in the lambda within the body (`m`, `p` and `q`). Here is an attempt to translate the code to English, from the end (bottom-right) to the beginning (top-left):

```
(define (cons x y)
    (lambda (m) (m x y))
```

> Whatever `m` is, and we suspect it is a function because it appears right next to a `(`, it must be applied over both `x` and `y`: this is the definition of `cons`ing `x` and `y`.

```
(define (car z)
    (z (lambda (p q) q)))
```

> Whatever `p` and `q` are, when something called `z` is applied, and `z` is something that accepts functions as its input, then the first one of `p` and `q` is selected: this is the definition of `car`.

For an example of "something that accepts functions as its input", we just need to look back to the definition of `cons`. So, this means `car` accepts `cons` as its input.

```
(car (cons 1 2)) ; looks indeed familiar and reassuring
(car (cons 1 (cons 2 '()))) ; is equivalent
(car '(1 2)) ; is also equivalent
(car z)
; if the previous two are equivalent, then z := '(1 2)
```

The last line means: a list is "something that accepts a function as its input".

Don't let your head spin at that moment! The list will only accept functions that can work on list elements, anyway. And this is the case precisely because we have re-defined `cons` the way that we have.

I think the main point from this exercise is "computation is bringing operations and data together, and it doesn't matter in which order you bring them together".

Comment: I put the bounty up to reward the current answer, but I have to wait 24 hours because reasons.

Comment: @GlassGhost : I hope the answer is useful to anyone else, then :)

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy to understand with the [combinatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) notation (implicitly translated to Scheme as currying functions, `f x y = z ==> (define f (λ (x) (λ (y) z)))`):

```
cons x y m = m x y
car z = z _K          ; _K p q = p
cdr z = z (_K _I)     ; _I x = x     _K _I p q = _I q = q
```

so we get

```
car (cons x y) = cons x y  _K     = _K  x y   =  x
cdr (cons x y) = cons x y (_K _I) = _K _I x y = _I y = y
```

so the definitions do what we expect. *Easy*.

In English, the `cons x y` value is a function that says *"if you'll give me a function of two arguments I'll call it with the two arguments I hold. Let it decide what to do with them, then!"*.

In other words, it expects a "continuation" function, and calls it with the two arguments used in its (the "pair") creation.