# How to return an anonymous function/lambda that receives a lambda/function?

Tags: lambda, rust, closures

It's possible to create a ordered pair (cons in Lisp) using a lambda and a function, as shown in [Use of lambda for cons/car/cdr definition in SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769348/use-of-lambda-for-cons-car-cdr-definition-in-sicp)

It also works in Python:

```py
def cons(x,y):
    return lambda m:m(x,y)
def car(z):
    return z(lambda x, y: x)
def cdr(z):
    return z(lambda x, y: y)
```

When I implement it in Rust, which is a statically-typed language:

```
fn cons(x: i32, y: i32) -> Box<Fn() -> Fn(i32, i32)> {
    Box::new(move |m| m(x, y));
}
```

it shows the errors:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
 --> src/main.rs:2:23
  |
2 |     Box::new(move |m| m(x, y));
  |                       ^^^^^^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:1:54
  |
1 |   fn cons(x: i32, y: i32) -> Box<Fn() -> Fn(i32, i32)> {
  |  ______________________________________________________^ starting here...
2 | |     Box::new(move |m| m(x, y));
3 | | }
  | |_^ ...ending here: expected box, found ()
  |
  = note: expected type `Box<std::ops::Fn() -> std::ops::Fn(i32, i32) + 'static + 'static>`
  = note:    found type `()`
```

How do I define the type of `m`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First little mistake: you added a semicolon at the end of your function body. This means that

```
Box::new(move |m|m(x,y));
```

is just a statement without side effects, much like `3 + 4;`. When you remove the semicolon, you will get a better compiler error, because now the compiler starts to connect your expression type with the return type.

Speaking of which: your return type is wrong, unfortunately. What you want, is to capture the two parameters `x` and `y` and return a closure which accepts *another* closure which is then called with the two parameters. This code works:

```
fn cons(x: i32, y: i32) ->  Box<Fn(&Fn(i32, i32))> {
    Box::new(move |m| m(x, y))
}
```

As you can see, the type of the returned closure is: `Fn(&Fn(i32, i32))`. A closure which accepts *another* closure as argument. You can use it like this:

```
let fun = cons(3, 7);
fun(&|x, y| println!("{}", x));
```

But we have two problems here:

1. Why the reference `&`? Closures in Rust are Voldemort types and you can only talk about them in terms of the traits they implement (e.g. the `Fn` trait). Usually, you have two ways to accept an arbitrary type which implements a trait `Foo`: with static dispatch and monomorphization (`fn bar<T: Foo>(x: T)`) or as trait object and with dynamic dispatch (`fn bar(x: &Foo)`). However, you are already returning a trait object (`Box<Fn(...)>`) and a trait object can't have generic methods (they can't be monomorphized for various reasons). This means that you *need* to accept a trait object yourself and since trait objects are unsized, they need to hide behind a reference or something like `Box`.
2. The closures don't return anything! Correct, because this again would require monomorphization, because Rust is statically typed. The examples you showed/linked are in dynamically typed language, where things like these are not a problem. In Rust, it's a different story. You *can* fake dynamic typing in Rust by using [`Box<Any>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) or something like that. But this is not really idiomatic and should be avoided. *Maybe* you really need it, but *maybe* you also want to incorrectly use patterns from other language in Rust and should instead think in a more rusty way about your problem ;-)