# car implementation in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write by myself the `cons` function in scheme. I have written this code:

```
(define (car. z)
    (z (lambda (p q) p)))
```

and I am trying to run :

```
(car. '(1 2 3))
```

I expect to get the number `1`, but it does not work properly.

Comment: In your definition of `car.` the argument z is used as a function applied to another function. In the call you pass instead a list, not a function.

Comment: @Renzo how do I need to change the function that I wrote

Comment: `car.` wants a "lambda-encoded" list, not a Scheme list. You need to implement the corresponding `cons.` operation, so you can create such lists.

Comment: As @molbdnilo said in the comment, you must decide if you want to represent lists as functional objects (the definition of the function `car.`), or as data structures (as in your call), and act uniformely. If you represent lists as functional objects, you must define first `cons`, and pass the result of this function to `car.`.

Comment: @Renzo can you define for me the cons. object please

Comment: In practice the genuine `car`, `cdr` and `cons` are builtins (and they have to be). Read Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_in_Small_Pieces)

Comment: There are many examples of how to implement these operations in the lambda calculus available online.

Comment: @molbdnilo can you refer me to one of this examples.

Comment: @user10853826, you can find everything in [this great free book online](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). Or see for instance this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769348/use-of-lambda-for-cons-car-cdr-definition-in-sicp)

Comment: `car`, `cdr`, and `cons` don't need to be builtin if your language has things like `struct` as a primitive construct (though in theory, people usually do it the other way around -- that is to build `struct` from `cons` -- because `cons` is much simpler).

Comment: `car.`'s argument must be a result of a call to `cons.`. `'(1 2 3)` is built by `(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 '())))`. mind the dot.

Comment: `(cons. a b)` creates a function that expects another function, and applies it to the two values so that that function can decide what to do with the two values: `(define ((cons. a b) f) (f a b))`. For instance, `((cons. a b) (lambda (p q) p)) = ((lambda (p q) p) a b) = a`.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement language data structures you need to supply constructors and accessors that conform to the contract:

```
(car (cons 1 2))   ; ==> 1
(cdr (cons 1 2))   ; ==> 2
(pair? (cons 1 2)) ; ==> 2
```

Here is an example:

```
(define (cons a d)
  (vector a d))
(define (car p)
  (vector-ref p 0))
(define (cdr p)
  (vector-ref p 1))
```

Now if you make an implementation you would implement `read` to be conformant to this way of doing pairs so that `'(1 2 3)` would create the correct data structure the simple rules above is still the same.

From looking at `car` I imagine `cons` looks like this:

```
(define (cons a d)
  (lambda (p) (p a d)))
```

It works with closures. Now A stack machine implementation of Scheme would analyze the code for free variables living passed their scope and thus create them as boxes. Closures containing `a`, and `d` aren't much different than vectors.

I urge you to implement a minimalistic Scheme interpreter. First in Scheme since you can use the host language, then a different than a lisp language. You can even do it [in an esoteric language](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/), but it is very time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Sylwester's answer is great. Here's another possible implementation of `null`, `null?`, `cons`, `car`, `cdr` -

```
(define null 'null)

(define (null? xs)
  (eq? null xs))

(define (cons a b)
  (define (dispatch message)
    (match message
      ('car a)
      ('cdr b)
      (_ (error 'cons "unsupported message" message))
  dispatch)

(define (car xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      (error 'car "cannot call car on an empty pair")
      (xs 'car)))

(define (cdr xs)
  (if (null? xs)
      (error 'cdr "cannot call cdr on an empty pair")
      (xs 'cdr)))
```

It works like this -

```
(define xs (cons 'a (cons 'b (cons 'c null))))

(printf "~a -> ~a -> ~a\n"
        (car xs)
        (car (cdr xs))
        (car (cdr (cdr xs))))
;; a -> b -> c
```

It raises errors in these scenarios -

```
(cdr null)
; car: cannot call car on an empty pair

(cdr null)
; cdr: cannot call cdr on an empty pair

((cons 'a 'b) 'foo)
;; cons: unsupported dispatch: foo
```

---

[`define/match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) adds a little sugar, if you like sweet things -

```
(define (cons a b)
  (define/match (dispatch msg)
    (('car) a)
    (('cdr) b)
    (('pair?) #t)
    ((_) (error 'cons "unsupported dispatch: ~a" msg)))
  dispatch)

((cons 1 2) 'car)   ;; 1
((cons 1 2) 'cdr)   ;; 2
((cons 1 2) 'pair?) ;; #t
((cons 1 2) 'foo)   ;; cons: unsupported dispatch: foo
```